# Sharepoint 2007: Move a document library to other site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How can I move a document library from one site to another on the same server.

Both source and destination sites are under the same root site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Sharepoint Content Deployment Wizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/) is awesome for this sort of thing. Highly recommended and open source.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success simply opening up explorer view on both sites and dragging and dropping. I guess it depends on how complex your migration is.